# Assembly version binding in C# .NET app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, versioning, .net-assembly, smo

I have an application that references Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo and other assemblies in the Microsoft.SqlServer namesapce. Visual Studio shows "Specific Version = False" for these references. the csproj looks like this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum" />
```

However, it seems that since the build machine has version 11, then when the application is run, the client will always look for version 11. Some machines will only have version 10 (upgrading is not an option).

I've hooked in to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event handler to essentially redirect it to version 10. This works. But, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in the app.config to avoid doing it in the code and having this code path. Is there a way in the app.config to do an  to say "use version 11 if you have it, otherwise use version 10" ?

Here's what I'm doing in code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolutionFailed;

private static Assembly OnAssemblyResolutionFailed(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    const string oldVersionName = "Version=10.0.0.0";
    const string newVersionName = "Version=11.0.0.0";
    Logger.Error("Failed to load assembly: " + args.Name + " from " + args.RequestingAssembly);

    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).FullName;
    if (assemblyName.Contains(oldVersionName))
    {
        assemblyName = assemblyName.Replace(oldVersionName, newVersionName);
    }
    else
    {
        assemblyName = assemblyName.Replace(newVersionName, oldVersionName);
    }
    Logger.Warn("Attemting to load: " + assemblyName);
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
    return assembly;
}
```

Comment: Does version 10 work in all scenarios with your application? One time when I did this, it worked in all but a couple of edge cases, which fortunately I caught just before release to production. Normally a major version number change means a change in the API. My fallback is to include a "ThirdParty" folder in my repo with the DLLs I need--version 11 in your case, and to reference those instead of implicitly referencing the installed versions (which could be 10 or 11, or none). Not sure if this is considered a good practice but it's always worked well for me.

Comment: Well, I'm fairly certain that redistributing the Microsoft DLLs in this case violates their terms. As for best practice, it's hard to say.

Comment: Point well taken, and not something I'd actually considered. I don't recall which assemblies I'd done it with in the past. I just knew I needed a specific DLL and that was one way to make it work. :)